# I'm indexing 4 different entities in Elastica search, is it possible to add different boost for one of them?

Tags: symfony, boost, elastica

I'm using Symfony 5.4. Indexing Item, Product, Event and Test entities. Since Test don't have content property, i want to add higher boost to Test title property, but i don't find information if it is event possible. Someone had same problem?

I tried adding this condition in main query, but what it applies higher boost to all Entities if one of them is Test.

```php
if ($this->indexManager->getIndex('test')) {`
    `$matchPhrase = new MatchPhrase();`
    `$matchPhrase->setFieldQuery('title.raw', $term);`
    `$matchPhrase->setFieldParam('title.raw', 'slop', 3);`
    `$matchPhrase->setFieldBoost('title.raw', 10);`
    `$bq->addShould($matchPhrase);`
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can boost a field like:

```
    [...]
    types:
        autor:
            properties:
                orig_id:
                    type: "integer"
                    property_path: origId
                    boost: 10
```

see https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/master/doc/indexes.md#nested-objects-in-foselasticabundle